# Weird Undefined Method Errors

Tags: java, android, android-intent

For some odd reason I recently got an error when working on an Android program in Eclipse. It was fine last night, but today I am getting an error. Here is the offending code:

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.exampleone" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
```

For the first line I get the error:

```
The method forName(String) is undefined for the type Class
```

For the second line I get the error:

```
The constructor Intent(Menu, Class) is undefined
```

The code was fine until today, when it suddenly starting saying there was a mistake

Comment: Can you copy the imports of your class???

Comment: Sounds like you've inadvertently either changed the project's configuration or the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility: you may have created your own class called `Class`. That would certainly cause both these errors. One way to check that (beyond just trying to find the offending class) is to change the first line to:

```
java.lang.Class ourClass = java.lang.Class.forName(
    "com.example.exampleone" + cheese);
```